# Nested filtering in elasticsearch with more than one term of the same nested type

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, nested, aggregation

I'm new to elasticsearch, so maybe my approach is plain wrong, but I want to make an index of recipes and allow the user to filter it ***down*** with the aggregated ingredients that are still found in the subset.

Maybe I'm using the wrong language to explain so maybe this example will clarify. I would like to search for recipes with the term `salt`; which results in three recipes:

1. with ingredients: salt, flour, water
2. with ingredients: salt, pepper, egg
3. with ingredients: water, flour, egg, salt

The aggregate on the results ingredients returns salt, flour, water, pepper, egg. When I filter with `flour` I only want recipe 1 and 3 to appear in the search results (and the aggregate on ingredients should only return salt, flour, water, egg and salt). When I add another filter `egg` I want only recipe 3 to appear (and the aggregate should only return water, flour, egg, salt).

I can't make the latter to work: one filter next to the default query ***does*** narrow down the results as desired but when adding the ***other*** term (egg) to the terms filter the results again start to include b as well, as if it were an OR filter. Adding `AND` however to the filter execution results in NO results ... what am I doing wrong?

My mapping:

```
{
  "recipe": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "analyzer": "dutch",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "ingredients": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "dutch",
            "include_in_parent": true,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "_all": "salt"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "ingredients",
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "ingredients.name": [
                "flour",
                "egg"
              ],
              "execution": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 50,
  "aggregations": {
    "ingredients": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "ingredients"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ingredients.name.raw"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a `nested` mapping here? Its main purpose is to keep relations between the sub-object attributes, but your `ingredients` field has just one attribute and can be modeled simply as a string field.

So, if you  update your mapping like this :

```
POST recipes
{
  "mappings": {
    "recipe": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ingredients": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can still index your recipes as :

```
{
  "title":"recipe b",
  "ingredients":["salt","pepper","egg"]
}
```

And this query gives you the result you are waiting for :

```
POST recipes/recipe/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "_all": "salt"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "ingredients": [
            "flour",
            "egg"
          ],
          "execution": "and"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 50,
  "aggregations": {
    "ingredients": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ingredients"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which is :

```
{
   ...
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.22295055,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "recipes",
            "_type": "recipe",
            "_id": "PP195TTsSOy-5OweArNsvA",
            "_score": 0.22295055,
            "_source": {
               "title": "recipe c",
               "ingredients": [
                  "salt",
                  "flour",
                  "egg",
                  "water"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "ingredients": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "egg",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "flour",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "salt",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "water",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was moving in this direction, but you gave the full answer (actually I added an array of strings next to the nested object, but as you suggest that is kind of overengineering at this moment). Thanks! Decomplicates matters a lot :)

Comment: Thanks is not enough: thank you very much for this extensive answer!

Comment: You're welcome :) The problem you had with the nested objects was that your `terms` filter criteria filters on a `ingredients` sub-object that will have BOTH `egg` and `flour` in the SAME sub-object.

Comment: Yep, that was what I realized too... but I had been experimenting also with nested boolean filters (even ones that queried the nested sets for each ingredient 'term'), anyway sometimes the solution is just to simplify stuff :)